What is the status of left-wing parties in Syria under the current caretaker government?
The transitional government that took power earlier this month (December 2024) is closely associated with Tahrir al-Sham, an Islamist group.
Most of the parties currently listed on the Wikipedia list of political parties in Syria are described as "left-wing" or "far left".
Do any of these parties have any form of representation in the current transitional government? If not, has the transitional government made any notable statements regarding their intent to include or exclude them in longer-term arrangements?

EDIT Dec. 29 2024: According to the recent interview with al-Sharaa in Al Arabiya and related reporting from the BBC, Tahir al-Sham is having discussions with the Syrian Democratic Forces (SDF). Implicitly at least, it seem likely that they would be included in the constitutional process, but I'm not sure if that has been an explicit commitment, and I see no mention of any other specific domestic political groups so far.

It says right in the link that the transitional government is just the salvation government in the same posts. It also says the government will expire in about 3 months and a constitution which does not yet exist, will be used to determine the formation of the next government. All the answers your looking for all seem to be in your own sources.

I don't think a question based on the traditional Western, and already flawed notion of left-vs-right parties makes much sense.  What does - per link - rating Baath as "far left" mean?  This was a nominally Socialist/Communist party at some point but has veered towards just extracting wealth for the Assads.  Then you'll have the nominally independent, but really pet "opposition" parties found in some dictatorships.  Are they "left"?.  Then, why ask just about "left" parties?  Would a moderate right party be unworthy?  Last, too early, no one knows right now.  VTC. opinion-based.

I'm not clear to me what's so unclear about the question. There is a list of parties and I want to know whether and how the provisional government is relating to them. I'm not asking anyone to predict the future and there is no need to editorialize about whether the listed parties are "really" left-wing or not. If they were loyal to Assad or not is relevant if and only if the provisional government is saying they refuse to deal with them for that reason.

Everything is clear except for "longer term". How long would that be for you? Months or years? Anyway even clear questions sometimes cannot get clear answers, for example if the asked for information isn't public. A lack of answers may be an indication that it's difficult to find sufficient information about it.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution No need to define long term, any statements from the provisional government would be relevant. And of course I recognize it's possible that there are no such public statements to answer the question, but I disagree with the comments that my question is self-answered or opinion-based.
